# Detect user touch movement direction?

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics, uibezierpath, uitouch

I have drawn alphabet A using `UIBezierPath`. It has three directions that demonstrate how user will draw this alphabet. Is there any way to check user touch movement is in same direction or not ?

[image]

Comment: you can fetch location(CGPoint) from UITouch.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati yes i can do that, but i want to know how to check user movement in same direction or not ?

Comment: keep all directions as a database. make a threshold distance (20-30 pixels), keep alive the `touchesBegan` point. on every `touchesMoved` calculate the distance and angle (start point and current point). compare and decide.

Comment: Try this with physics engine ?

Comment: @Saurabh which physics engine ? will physics engine give me direction of user movement ? all the app i am developing is a UIKit base

Comment: you can determine the direction either up,down,left right based on the touch points. Or How bout s swipe gesture ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. It will give you the current position, translation from the starting point, and the current velocity. If you keep track of the velocity, you will know if it matches the previous velocity.

You can use `-[UIBezierPath containsPoint:]` to determine whether the gesture is still within the A.

Like so:

```
- (void)panRecognizerFired:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer {
    switch (panRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
        {
            // ignore it until it changes to UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
            return;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {
            // handle gesture start here

            // change this to a break if you want a beginning touch to be processed
            // the same as a movement
            return;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        {
            // handle gesture end here - clean up and undo whatever happened
            // in UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, show a new controller or something, etc

            // change this to a break if you want an ending touch to be processed
            // the same as a movement
            return;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        {
            // abort! undo everything here
            return;
        }
        default:
            // it moved! break to process that movement
            break;
    }

    CGPoint location = [panRecognizer locationInView:self.theViewThatHasTheLetterAInIt];
    CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.theViewThatHasTheLetterAInIt];
    CGPoint velocity = [panRecognizer velocityInView:self.theViewThatHasTheLetterAInIt];

    BOOL isLocationInsidePath = [self.letterABezierPath containsPoint:location];

    // make decisions based on isLocationInsidePath and velocity here...
}
```

To ensure that this gesture is only allowed to begin near the right number, make self conform to the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol and set `self.panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self`. Then you can restrict starting locations with this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.panGestureRecognizer) {
        CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.theViewThatHasTheLetterAInIt];

        // implement this property to return the center of the 1, 2, or 3 circle
        CGPoint targetCenter = self.currentTargetCenter;

        CGFloat distanceX = location.x - targetCenter.x;
        CGFloat distanceY = location.y - targetCenter.y;
        CGFloat distanceDiagonalSquared = (distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY);

        const CGFloat maxDistance = 20.f;

        return (distanceDiagonalSquared <= maxDistance * maxDistance);
    }

    return YES;
}
```